# Arduino- Increase range of duty cycle PWM on mega 2560?

Tags: arduino

I used arduino mega 2560. Because `analogWrite` just have value from 0 to 255, if I want to increase range example 4096: `analogWrite(9, 4096)`. Is this impossible? How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

use `map` for example

```
map(x, 0, 255, 0, 4095);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Arduino Mega 2560 documentation](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560):

> PWM: 2 to 13 and 44 to 46. Provide 8-bit PWM output with the analogWrite() function.

`255` is the maximum you can get with 8 bits and will be equal to 100% of duty cycle time

If your input is higher than 255, you can use @Ôrel method with the `map()` function.